# Replying to certain message in Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-php

I am making an event organisation platform. Whenever user creates an event, the candidate gets an email notification as well as sms notification asking whether the suggested time fits or not. The problem is that since it is event organisation, there may be more than one occurance of candidate's mobile phone. So I need to have some unique information to identify to which event candidate is responding to.

I have tried identify using Message SID, but then I realised that Message SID is different on reply message.

So my question would be: is there any way to authenticate to which message candidate is replying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Twilio developer evangelist here.

Because every message is idempotent, you wouldn't be able to track them just via the call sid. however, there's way to get around that such as passing a code that goes with each message which you can then read, or using cookies.

I think you are probably going to be more successful using cookies, and luckily enough there is an article on twilio's website that describes just how to do that. And because I noticed you're using PHP, I'm pointing you directly to the PHP article on [tracking SMS conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/tracking-conversations).

Hope this helps you

Comment: yes, i have seen this article. But i haven't understood it fully. Does it mean that I simply have to use `$_SESSION` variable to store cookies in it?

Comment: It means you need to start the session, and then store the information you want to persist on it. The session information are then stored on Twilio's servers. You can then have a unique cookie for each from/to phone number pair (say 415-555-2222 and 415-555-1111). If you find a cookie that has this value, you know which conversation you are tracking. Hope this helps